# Generating sets of topology on $C_b(\mathbb T)$ with supremum Norm?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, functions

Can someone tell me what sets generate the topology on the continuous bounded function on the 1-dim Torus $C_b(\mathbb T)$ with the supremum norm?

Are the sets $\left\{ f \in C_b(\mathbb T) : |f|<R \right\}_{\{ R>0\}}$ a generating set?

Thanks

Comment: yes, since they are a base of neighbourhoods of $0\in C_b(\mathbb{T})$.